# How to remove namespace from generated JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjc

Using JAVA 7, XJC.

The xsd is provided by a 3rd party that uses .NET.

The issue at hand is that when I marshal the object into XML I get something along these lines:

```
<SalesOrder xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RKLServiceQueue">
  <ns2:BillToAddrLine1>7315 N Ritter Ave</ns2:BillToAddrLine1>
  <ns2:BillToAddrLine2></ns2:BillToAddrLine2>
  <ns2:BillToAddrName>David Kruse</ns2:BillToAddrName>
  <ns2:BillToCity>Indianapolis</ns2:BillToCity>
  <ns2:BillToCountryID>USA</ns2:BillToCountryID>
  <ns2:BillToPostalCode>46250</ns2:BillToPostalCode>
</SalesOrder
```

The service is expecting something like this:

```
  <SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RKLServiceQueue">
    <BillToAddrLine1>String content</BillToAddrLine1>
    BillToAddrLine2>String content</BillToAddrLine2>
    <BillToAddrLine3>String content</BillToAddrLine3>
    <BillToAddrLine4>String content</BillToAddrLine4>
    <BillToAddrLine5>String content</BillToAddrLine5>
    <BillToAddrName>String content</BillToAddrName>
    <BillToCity>String content</BillToCity>
  </SalesOrder>
```

Here is part of the xsd as well

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RKLServiceQueue" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RKLServiceQueue" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="SalesOrder">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToAddrLine1" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToAddrLine2" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToAddrLine3" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToAddrLine4" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToAddrLine5" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToAddrName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToCity" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToCountryID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToPostalCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BillToStateID" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
```

I have conducted test on SoapUI to verify.

I have done a bit of searching on the web, including stackoverflow and it points to using NamespacePrefixMapper but that does not seem to do the the trick.  I keep getting the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.namespacePrefixMapper value: com.heritage.jobs.MyPrefixMapper@29545330
```

Here is the mapper

```java
import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;


/**
 * 
 */
public class MyPrefixMapper extends NamespacePrefixMapper
{
    private static final String FOO_PREFIX = ""; // DEFAULT NAMESPACE
    private static final String FOO_URI = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RKLServiceQueue";


    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper#getPreferredPrefix(java.lang.String,
     * java.lang.String, boolean)
     */
    @Override
    public String getPreferredPrefix(final String pNameSpaceUri, final String pSuggestion, final boolean pRequirePrefix)
    {
        if (FOO_URI.equals(pNameSpaceUri))
        {
            return FOO_PREFIX;
        }

        return pSuggestion;
    }
```

Here is what I am using to call it:

```java
final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SalesOrder.class);

marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

final MyPrefixMapper prefixMapper = new MyPrefixMapper();
try
{
        marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.bind.marshaller.namespacePrefixMapper", prefixMapper);
}
catch (final PropertyException e)
{
LOG.error("perform(CronJobModel)", e);
}
```

I am not clear as to what I am missing to make this work - How can I remove the namespace ns from each of the fields/properties?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the annotations in package-info.java like this:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://myOutput", xmlns = {@XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "http://myOutput")}, elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

This way I got rid of the ns2 on the root element...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```java
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.newDocument();

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RequestXml.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(new RequestXml(), document);

new NamespaceRemover().remove(document);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(writer));

System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

The `NamespaceRemover` is implemented as follows:

```java
public class NamespaceRemover {

    public void remove(Node node) {
        Document doc = node.getOwnerDocument();

        String localName = tryToResolveLocalName(node.getNodeName());
        if (localName != null)
            doc.renameNode(node, null, localName);

        NamedNodeMap attributes = node.getAttributes();
        if (attributes != null)
            remove(attributes);

        remove(node.getChildNodes());
    }

    protected String tryToResolveLocalName(String nodeName) {
        if (nodeName == null || nodeName.startsWith("#"))
            return null;

        String[] tagParts = nodeName.split(":");
        return tagParts[tagParts.length - 1];
    }

    public void remove(NodeList childNodes) {
        for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++)
            remove(childNodes.item(i));
    }

    public void remove(NamedNodeMap attributes) {
        List<String> attrsToBeRemoved = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node attr = attributes.item(i);
            if (attr.getNodeName().startsWith("xmlns:") || "xmlns".equals(attr.getNodeName()))
                attrsToBeRemoved.add(attr.getNodeName());
            else
                remove(attributes.item(i));
        }

        for (String attrToBeRemoved : attrsToBeRemoved)
            attributes.removeNamedItem(attrToBeRemoved);
    }

}
```

The `NamespaceRemover` can also be used to remove namespaces from sub-trees of your XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `internal` in `import` and in `property` like this:

```
import com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.NamespacePrefixMapper;
```

... and,

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.namespacePrefixMapper", prefixMapper);
```